# Delphi TIdTCPClient connection pool in a multithread environment

Tags: tcp, delphi, connection-pool

I want to use `TIdTCPClient` to connect to Redis from a web server application made with Delphi and `TWebModule`. Currently on WebModule creation I create a new `TIdTCPClient` and on web module destroy, I disconnect and free the resource. All works... But this way I create a new connection on every new request and after a lot of time there is a growing number of `TIME_WAIT` sockets.

I would like to implement a global connection pool with a fixed number of connections always open.

NB: I have omitted redis logic, in this example is important only TCP connection pool

**Redis.Pool.pas**

```
unit Redis.Pool;  

interface

  uses
    Windows,
    System.Classes,
    System.SysUtils,
    System.SyncObjs,
    System.Threading,
    System.DateUtils,
    IdTCPClient;

  type

    EConnPoolException = class(Exception);

    IRedisConnection = Interface(IInterface)
      function Connection: TIdTCPClient;
      function GetRefCount: Integer;
      function GetLastAccess: TDateTime;
      function GetIsConnected: boolean;
      property LastAccess: TDateTime read GetLastAccess;
      property RefCount: Integer read GetRefCount;
      property IsConnected: boolean read GetIsConnected;
    end;

    // The TRedisConnection class also contains two member fields, 
    // FCriticalSection and FSemaphore. Both of these members are used to point 
    // to a TCriticalSection and a semaphore (a THandle), both of which are 
    // maintained by the TFixedRedisPool class (and are assigned to these 
    // members by the TFixedRedisPool instance when it creates an instance 
    // of the connection module). 
    // The critical section class is used to synchronize access to the internal 
    // reference count of the connection pool instances, and the semaphore 
    // controls access to instances of the TRedisConnection class. This is 
    // shown in the _AddRef and _Release method implementations, shown here. 
    TRedisConnection = class(TInterfacedObject, IRedisConnection)
    private
      FConnection: TIdTCPClient;
    protected
      FRefCount: Integer;
      FLastAccess: TDateTime;
      // When the TRedisConnection is created the
      // connection pool that creates the object
      // will assign its critical section to this field.
      // The object will use this critical section
      // to synchronize access to its reference count.
      FCriticalSection: TCriticalSection;
      // This semaphore points to the FixedConnectionPool's
      // semaphore. It will be used to call ReleaseSemaphore
      // from the _Release method of the TRedisConnection.
      FSemaphore: THandle;
      // These two static methods are reintroduced
      // in order to implement lifecycle management
      // for the interface of this object.
      // Normally, unlike normal COM objects, Delphi
      // TComponent descendants are not lifecycle managed
      // when used in interface references.
      function _AddRef: Integer; stdcall;
      function _Release: Integer; stdcall;
      function GetRefCount: Integer;
      function GetLastAccess: TDateTime;
      function GetIsConnected: boolean;
    public
      constructor Create; overload;
      destructor Destroy; override;
      function Connection: TIdTCPClient;
    end;

    TCleanupThread = class;

    TFixedRedisPool = class(TObject)
    private
      FPool: array of IRedisConnection;
      FPoolSize: Integer;
      FTimeout: Integer;
      FCleanupThread: TCleanupThread;
      // This semaphore is used to limit the number of
      // simultaneous connections. When the nth+1 connection
      // is requested, it will be blocked until a connection
      // becomes available.
      FSemaphore: THandle;
      // This is the critical section that synchronizes
      // access to the connection module reference counts
      FCriticalSection: TCriticalSection;
    public
      // This overloaded constructor takes two optional
      // parameters. These parameters specify the size
      // of the connection pool, as well as how long idle
      // connections in the connection pool will be kept.
      constructor Create(const APoolSize: Integer = 10; const ACleanupDelayMinutes: Integer = 5; const ATimeoutms: Integer = 2000); overload;
      destructor Destroy; override;
      // This function returns an object
      // that implements the IRedisConnection interface.
      // This object can be a data module, as was
      //done in this example.
      function GetConnection: IRedisConnection;
    end;

    // This thread class is used by the connection pool
    // object to cleanup idle connections after a
    // configurable period of time.
    TCleanupThread = class(TThread)
    private
      FCleanupDelay: Integer;
    protected
      // When the thread is created, this critical section
      // field will be assigned the connection pool's
      // critical section. This critical section is
      // used to synchronize access to data module
      // reference counts.
      FCriticalSection: TCriticalSection;
      FFixedConnectionPool: TFixedRedisPool;
      procedure Execute; override;
      constructor Create(const ACreateSuspended: Boolean; const ACleanupDelayMinutes: Integer);
    end;

// Global Connection Pool
var
  RedisConnPool: TFixedRedisPool;

implementation

// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// +++ TRedisConnection ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

constructor TRedisConnection.Create;
begin
  FConnection := TIdTCPClient.Create;
  FConnection.Connect('LOCALHOST', 6379);
end;

destructor TRedisConnection.Destroy;
begin
  FConnection.Disconnect;
  FConnection.Free;

  inherited;
end;

function TRedisConnection._AddRef: Integer;
begin
  // increment the reference count
  FCriticalSection.Enter;
  try
    Inc(FRefCount);
    Result := FRefCount;
  finally
    FCriticalSection.Leave;
  end;
end;

function TRedisConnection._Release: Integer;
begin
  // decrement the reference count
  FCriticalSection.Enter;
  try
    Dec(FRefCount);
    Result := FRefCount;

    // if not more references, call Destroy
    if Result = 0 then
      Destroy
    else
      Self.FLastAccess := Now;
  finally
    FCriticalSection.Leave;
    if FRefCount = 1 then
      ReleaseSemaphore(FSemaphore, 1, nil);
  end;
end;

function TRedisConnection.GetRefCount: Integer;
begin
   Result := FRefCount;
end;

function TRedisConnection.GetLastAccess: TDateTime;
begin
   Result := Self.FLastAccess;
end;

function TRedisConnection.GetIsConnected: boolean;
begin
   Result := Self.FConnection.Connected;
end;

function TRedisConnection.Connection: TIdTCPClient;
begin
  Result := Self.FConnection;
end;


// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// +++ TFixedRedisPool +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

constructor TFixedRedisPool.Create(const APoolSize: Integer = 10; const ACleanupDelayMinutes: Integer = 5; const ATimeoutms: Integer = 2000);
begin
  FPoolSize        := APoolSize;
  FTimeout         := ATimeoutms;
  FSemaphore       := CreateSemaphore(nil, APoolSize, APoolSize, '');
  FCriticalSection := TCriticalSection.Create;

  // Set the length of the connection pool
  SetLength(FPool, APoolSize);
  
  // Create and start the cleanup thread
  FCleanupThread := TCleanupThread.Create(True, ACleanupDelayMinutes);
  with FCleanupThread do
  begin
    FreeOnTerminate      := True;
    Priority             := tpLower;
    FFixedConnectionPool := Self;
    Start;
  end;
end;

function TFixedRedisPool.GetConnection: IRedisConnection;
var
  I:                Integer;
  aRedisConnection: TRedisConnection;
  aWaitResult:      Integer;
begin
  Result := nil;

  aWaitResult := WaitForSingleObject(FSemaphore, FTimeout);
  if aWaitResult <> WAIT_OBJECT_0 then raise EConnPoolException.Create('TFixedRedisPool.GetConnection pool timeout.');

  FCriticalSection.Enter;
  try
    for I := Low(FPool) to High(FPool) do
    begin
      // If FPool[i] = nil, the IRedisConnection has
      // not yet been created. Create it, initialize
      // it, and return it. If FPool[i] <> nil, then
      // check to see if its RefCount = 1 (only the pool
      // is referencing the object).
      if FPool[I] = nil then
      begin
        aRedisConnection := TRedisConnection.Create;
        aRedisConnection.FCriticalSection := Self.FCriticalSection;
        aRedisConnection.FSemaphore := Self.FSemaphore;
        FPool[I] := aRedisConnection;
        Result := FPool[I];
        Exit;
      end;
      // if FPool[i].FRefCount = 1 then
      // the connection is available. Return it.
      if (FPool[I].RefCount = 1) and FPool[I].IsConnected then
      begin
        Result := FPool[I];
        Exit;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    FCriticalSection.Leave;
  end;
end;


// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// +++ TCleanupThread ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

constructor TCleanupThread.Create(const ACreateSuspended: Boolean; const ACleanupDelayMinutes: Integer);
begin
  // always create suspended
  inherited Create(True);

  FCleanupDelay := ACleanupDelayMinutes;
  
  // Start if not created suspended
  if not(ACreateSuspended) then Start;
end;


destructor TFixedRedisPool.Destroy;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  FCleanupThread.Terminate;

  FCriticalSection.Enter;
  try
    for I := Low(FPool) to High(FPool) do
      FPool[I] := nil;
    SetLength(FPool,0);
  finally
    FCriticalSection.Leave;
  end;
  FCriticalSection.Free;

  CloseHandle(FSemaphore);

  inherited;
end;

procedure TCleanupThread.Execute;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  while True do
  begin
    if Terminated then Exit;

    // Sleep per delay
    Sleep(FCleanupDelay * 1000 * 60);
    if Terminated then Exit;

    FFixedConnectionPool.FCriticalSection.Enter;
    try
      for I := Low(FFixedConnectionPool.FPool) to High(FFixedConnectionPool.FPool) do begin

        if FFixedConnectionPool.FPool[I] = nil then continue;

        // if the connection exists, has no external reference,
        // and has not been used lately, release it
        if not(FFixedConnectionPool.FPool[I].IsConnected) or (FFixedConnectionPool.FPool[I].RefCount = 1) and (MinutesBetween(FFixedConnectionPool.FPool[I].LastAccess, Now) > FCleanupDelay) then begin
          FFixedConnectionPool.FPool[I] := nil;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      FFixedConnectionPool.FCriticalSection.Leave;
    end;
  end;
end;



initialization
  RedisConnPool := TFixedRedisPool.Create(10, 5, 2000);

finalization
  FreeAndNil(RedisConnPool);

end.
```

usage

```
uses Redis.Pool;

var
   aConn: IRedisConnection;
begin
  // RedisConnPool is blobal var into Redis.Pool
  aConn := RedisConnPool.GetConnection;
  try
    // I have omitted redis logic in this example is important only TCP connection pool..
    // aConn.Connection.GET('REDIS_KEY');
    aConn.Connection.IOHandler.Write('HELLO');
  finally
    aConn := nil;
  end;

end;
```

The question is: Is my implementation thread safe in a in a multithread environment like a `TWebModule` application?